# React.js Deployed But Got Black or White Blank Screen

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, netlify

Hello I made Twitter Clone Coding with Firebase and React
It worked Well on Local server
but When I deployed on GitPages or Netilfy it finally doesn't work I don't know How to fix it
Plz Help me Guys

This Site What I Deployed
https://confident-sammet-d0361b.netlify.app/

```
Router.jsx


import {HashRouter as Router, Route , Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "routes/auth";
import Home from "../routes/home";
import Profile from "../routes/profile";
import Navigation from "./navigation";

const AppRouter = ({ refreshUser, isLoggedIn, userObj }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      {isLoggedIn && <Navigation userObj={userObj} />}
      <Switch>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <div
            style={{
              maxWidth: 890,
              width: "100%",
              margin: "0 auto",
              marginTop: 80,
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home userObj={userObj} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/profile">
              <Profile userObj={userObj} refreshUser={refreshUser} />
            </Route>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Auth />
            </Route>
          </>
        )}
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the console you need to deal with:

```
Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.
```

Specifically, it looks like it's coming from Firebase Auth.

Comment: Thank You for  your question I tried to found it But It isn't  Easy Haha ... still Doesn't work anyway Thank you so much Have a good day !